# LINQ Faster way to insert a large amount of data into SQL?

Tags: sql, performance, linq, insert

I have a large amount of data in some files, the data cannot even be in memory. As of now I am parsing the data, and after each entity is parsed, the parsing class raises an event, in this event I am, using LINQ, inserting an item into the corresponding Database table. When a whole file (have also tried all files) is parsed, any inserts are submitted to the database. The problem is that this takes way too long. I have left the program running over night and it did not even finish. The data is about 1.5gb of data on disk. How can I speed up my insertions? I am leveraging parallelisation for parsing, and it takes not time at all to parse, it is the insertions that are creating a huge bottleneck.

Comment: Try having a look at where most of the time is spent ! Parallelisation  might be hard to put into place here. You should already try improving the performance without multithreading

Comment: You need to look at bulk insert - not using Linq.

Comment: LINQ what? LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework?

Comment: I'd use `SqlBulkCopy` as recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166338/can-i-do-a-very-large-insert-with-linq-to-sql

Comment: Perhaps you should look at this article, http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/LINQ/InsertAndDeletes.htm

Comment: Have you tried batching the inserts into transactions?

Comment: I believe LINQ uses transactions by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bulk insert helped, along with a pipeline model, and general code efficiency. It's never going to take less than 30 minutes unless you're on a fast machine with fast internet...